# coredata - fetch distinct rows having maximum value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to setup my NSFetchRequest to core data to retrieve the rows "unique name which have greater rate"

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rate = max(rate)"];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"name"]];
request.predicate = predicate;
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
```

But the above return only one row which have maximum rate.

required sample

```
  name | rate | factor |
_______|______|________|
John   |  3.2 |    7   |
Betty  |  5.5 |    7   |
Betty  |  7.1 |    2   |
Betty  |  3.1 |    2   |
Edward |  5.5 |    1   |
Edward |  4.5 |    2   |
John   |  4.3 |    4   |
```

How would i set up the request to return an array like

```
John,  4.3, 4
Betty, 7.1, 2
Edward,5.5, 1
```

And can we sort it (sort by rate desc) with the fetch query itself ? So the result array will be

```
Betty, 7.1, 2
Edward,5.5, 1
John,  4.3, 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `propertiesToGroupBy` property of your `NSFetchRequest` to include "name".

Note: you may have to aggregate the factor column in some way as well, for the group by to work.

Comment: btw I was not able to get the correct value of 'factor'.